# Audio autoplaying even when it's turned off

Tags: javascript, html

I have JS that plays random song from playlist, but I have problem, when I tried everything offline, then everything worked, but when I upload the site to hosting the audio autoplays itself when entering site.
My code:

```
<audio id="audioplayer">
</audio>
<a onclick="document.getElementById('audioplayer') .play()"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></a>
<script>
    var lastSong = null;
    var selection = null;
    var playlist = ["my music here"];
    var isPlaying = false;
    var player = document.getElementById("audioplayer");
    player.autoplay = false;
    player.addEventListener("ended", selectRandom);

    function selectRandom(){
        while(selection == lastSong){
            selection = Math.floor(Math.random() * playlist.length);
        }
        lastSong = selection;
        player.src = playlist[selection];
    }

    selectRandom();
    player.play();
     
</script>
```

Comment: It looks like it should always start playing since `player.play()` is not contained in a function. Have you tried removing it?

Comment: @DeMO thank you, that was it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `player.play()` is not contained in a function so it will always start playing. You should try removing it.

> @DeMO thank you, that was it! – Tudis May 1 at 17:29